# Linking Errors in XCode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, asihttprequest, automatic-ref-counting, clang

After adding ASIHTTPRequest to my project (which incidentally I've now removed) I get linking errors targeting iOS 5 with ARC on XCode 4. I get a cryptic stack trace, but is there any other way of pinning this down to a (lack of?) dependency or a particular file. The full error is:

```
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/echilon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenPing-gymuuvfpbmmxkbffpepzepewikrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ChickenPing.app.dSYM /Users/echilon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenPing-gymuuvfpbmmxkbffpepzepewikrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ChickenPing.app/ChickenPing
    cd /Users/echilon/Documents/ChickenPing
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/echilon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenPing-gymuuvfpbmmxkbffpepzepewikrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ChickenPing.app/ChickenPing -o /Users/echilon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ChickenPing-gymuuvfpbmmxkbffpepzepewikrk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ChickenPing.app.dSYM
```

Comment: none of that looks like an error

Comment: Try to clean your project and rebuild. There could be some old hooks to the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ultimately was caused by lack of ARC support in ASIHTTPRequest. Despite trying compiling the source separately, I was forced to abandon it and use something else.